# Cordova build android faild with following error

Tags: android, cordova, build

C:\phonegap\apps\test>cordova build android

```
[javac]@Override public void close() throws IOException {
[javac]      ^
[javac] Note: * uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 100 errors
```

BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\zonup technologies\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:60
1: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Documents and Settings\zonup technologies\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:72
0: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Documents and Settings\zonup technologies\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:73
4: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

C:\phonegap\apps\test>